# Rearranging data to a matrix for contour plot

Tags: r, plot

I have this data:

```
df = structure(list(vint1 = c(10L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 10L, 7L, 1L, 8L, 
3L, 7L, 9L, 1L, 5L, 5L), vint2 = c(3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 
5L, 6L, 3L, 10L, 4L, 1L, 8L, 8L), vnum1 = c(-1.17289752533732, 
-0.559339864207054, -0.595443000061417, -0.396535659893954, 0.788141517690765, 
-0.655833840195406, -2.26371235489487, -1.34850886354386, -0.0218824069117636, 
0.554324892501117, 2.37117531121636, 0.248289029610446, -1.21942427707135, 
-1.4366686196659, -2.64837580107992)), .Names = c("vint1", "vint2", 
"vnum1"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```

when I give following command on R prompt, it works:

```
with(df[vint1==10 & vint2==3,], mean(vnum1))
```

[1] -1.172898

But following function give incorrect result:

```
testfn = function(df2, a,b,c)
{
    with(df2[df2[[a]]==10 & df2[[b]]==3,], mean(df2[[c]]))
}
```

when I give the command:

```
testfn(df,1,2,3)

[1] -0.5571128
```

This value is mean of all entries from 3rd column (vnum1)

```
mean(df$vnum1)
[1] -0.5571128
```

Following function also does not work:

```
testfn = function(df2, name1,name2,name3)
{
    with(df2[name1==10 & name2==3,], mean(name3))
}
```

If I use: with(df2[df2$name1==10 & df$name2==3,], mean(df2$name3))
I get the error: 
argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

I have to subsequently allot this value to a create a matrix, which can used to create a contour plot:

```
mycontour = function(df2, a,b,c)
{
    mymat = matrix(0,10,10)
    for(i in 1:10)   for(j in 1:10)
        mymat[i,j]= with(df2[df2[[a]]==i & df2[[b]]==j,], mean(df2[[c]]))
    filled.contour(mymat)
}
```

This should create a contour plot with two ordered number (1:10) variables as the x and y axis, and contour accoring to the third (numeric) variable (means of values corresponding to 2 factor levels).  How can I solve this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your first `with` command does not work (`vint1` and `vint2` are not defined outside of `df`); perhaps use `mean( df[df$vint1==10 & df$vint2==3, 'vnum1'] )` (one of many ways). Also, within the first function definition, `with` is not doing anything for you.

Comment: Are you getting a lot of `NaN` values?  I am.  There's no 2 in column one when you loop it.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The code: mean(df2[df2[[a]]==i & df2[[b]]==j, c]) works very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first instance of your function,

```
testfn = function(df2, a,b,c)
{
    with(df2[df2[[a]]==10 & df2[[b]]==3,], mean(df2[[c]]))
}
```

`with` is doing nothing at all for you. You could alternatively use:

```
testfn2 <- function(df2, a,b,c) {
    mean(df2[df2[[a]]==10 & df2[[b]]==3, c])
}
testfn2(df,1,2,3)
## [1] -1.172898
```

If you'd prefer to use names in your function arguments, you'll need
to do some substitute magic. For this, I'll humbly refer you to Hadley
Wickham's [Subsetting](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html) page
for a thorough explanation.

To create the matrix, again your use of `with` is doing nothing. Try this:

```
mycontour2 <- function(df2, a,b,c) {
    nr <- 10 ; nc <- 10
    mm <- matrix(0, nr=nr, nc=nc)
    for (i in 1:nr)
        for (j in 1:nc)
            mm[i,j] <- mean(df2[df2[[a]]==i & df2[[b]]==j, c])
    mm[is.nan(mm)] <- 0
    mm
}
round(mycontour2(df, 1,2,3), digits=2)
##       [,1] [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6] [,7]  [,8] [,9] [,10]
##  [1,] -0.81    0  0.00 -0.58 -1.35  0.00    0  0.00    0  0.00
##  [2,]  0.00    0  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00    0  0.00    0  0.00
##  [3,]  0.00    0  0.55  0.00  0.00  0.00    0  0.00    0  0.00
##  [4,]  0.00    0  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00    0  0.00    0  0.00
##  [5,]  0.00    0  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00    0 -2.04    0  0.00
##  [6,]  0.00    0  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00    0  0.00    0  0.00
##  [7,]  0.00    0  0.79  0.00  0.00 -2.26    0  0.00    0  2.37
##  [8,]  0.00    0  0.00  0.00  0.00 -0.02    0  0.00    0  0.00
##  [9,]  0.00    0  0.00  0.25  0.00  0.00    0  0.00    0  0.00
## [10,]  0.00    0 -1.17 -0.66  0.00  0.00    0  0.00    0  0.00
```

Another way which is close but does not include missing indices:

```
require(reshape2)
round(acast(df, vint1 ~ vint2, value.var='vnum1', fun.aggregate=mean, fill=0), digits=3)
##       1     3     4     5     6     8   10
## 1  -0.81  0.00 -0.58 -1.35  0.00  0.00 0.00
## 3   0.00  0.55  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 0.00
## 5   0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 -2.04 0.00
## 7   0.00  0.79  0.00  0.00 -2.26  0.00 2.37
## 8   0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 -0.02  0.00 0.00
## 9   0.00  0.00  0.25  0.00  0.00  0.00 0.00
## 10  0.00 -1.17 -0.66  0.00  0.00  0.00 0.00
```

Notice that columns 2 and 7 are missing as are rows 2, 4, and 6, all
of which were zeroes in the previous matrix. If you have a larger
dataset where you are not missing any of the x or y values, then
perhaps this will work for you. (There are ways to work around this,
though, if you need it to be more robust. If so, holler.)

Comment: Thanks. Your solution: mean(df2[df2[[a]]==i & df2[[b]]==j, c]) works very well.